# Java Project Assignment

Tags: java

Help! I want to create a java program that finds the highest even integer among the values entered by the user. Stop asking values when a value less than 1 have been entered. If no even integer is entered, display "No Even Integer"

Here is the sample output that I want to achieve:

Enter value: 3

Enter value :8

Enter Value:1

Enter value: 6

Enter value: 3

Enter value: 4

Enter Value: -5

Highest even integer: 8

There's An Error about it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at Project.main(Project.java:14)
```

Answer:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int max = 0;

        while (true) {

            System.out.println("Enter value:");

            int m = scan.nextInt();

            if (m < 1)
                break;

            if ((m % 2 == 0) && (m > max))
                max = m;
        }

        if (max == 0)
            System.out.println("No Even Integer");

        else
            System.out.println("Highest even integer=" + max);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you format your code please?  Neither I nor anyone else will look at it until you do.

Comment: Most  likely this is not the code that produced the errors you've mentioned. Just copying, pasting and running the code you provided above gives the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I see a potential problem when you give an empty standard input to the program, `scan.nextInt()` can't read any integer.

Comment: the output is say : No even integer

Answer (score 0):

Your code is giving error because it might be stuck into an infinite loop. Instead of setting the condition true, try using your actual condition expression of logic in while loop. Here's the correct code for it

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class Project {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int max = 0; 
        System.out.println ("Enter value:"); 
        int m = scan.nextInt ();
        while(m >= 1)
        { 
            if ((m%2 == 0) && (m > max)) max = m; 
            System.out.println ("Enter value:"); 
            m = scan.nextInt();
        }

        if (max == 0) System.out.println (max); 

        else System.out.println ("Highest even integer=" + max);
        }
}
```

Comment: Enter value:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at Project.main(Project.java:9)  Same Error

Comment: Try using some other Compiler because, an online compiler may have issues get input from the keyboard such as Scanner. I have tried this code and your code as well in NetBeans IDE and its works